# How can you ensure at least once notifications in a distributed system?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Lets say I have a calendar event:

```
calendar_event (
    id UUID,
    start_time timestamp,
    end_time timestamp, 
    ...
)
```

And I let users create notifications for those events

```
notification (
     id UUID, 
     event_id UUID, # the id of the event in calendar_event
     notification_time timestamp, # the time the notification should be sent
     notification_sent boolean DEFAULT false, # true if the notification has been sent
)
```

And this app is used enough that I have multiple nodes (restful java applications for example) processing create events, create notifications, and delete notifications etc. and storing that data in some database, e.g. MySQL.

And lets also assume that it is critical that I send the notification on time, and users are able to update notifications in the very near future.

**How can I ensure that each notification is sent at least once?**

---

We could have another app that is polling every minute, and then sending the notifications, but if that app is down for any length of time we will have missed notifications. If we mark notifications as sent using the boolean field, then we could catch up, but we could be late. And if we're storing the next minute, and a notification is deleted, and should therefore not be sent, we will send a notification when we should not.

I am reminded of a queue, but with some different properties; we need to sort by notification_time, not insert time, and we need to allow deletes.

Comment: Why are you hesitant about queues? It's the right way, you just need delayed queuing (or implement it yourself, it's not so hard), persistence and deletion (or skip-consuming for conventional message brokers)

Comment: I wasn't hesitant about a queue. It's just that you're typical queue doesn't have the right semantics, and you have to do some extra work to massage the ordering. I didn't know about the DelayQueue until I did some more searching.

Answer (score 1):

> How can you ensure at least once notifications in a distributed
>   system?

Well there are many ways to achieve this, but considering you scenario, queues are the simple option. You requirement is notification reliability, you can send messages(notifications) in your case to multiple queues, you can either you try primary queue, if failed, send to secondary. On the reading end you can try primary queue if fails read from secondary. Also you will have to make sure the queues are on different hardware/machines etc. This way you can shield from hardware failures. Depending on your underlying platform, cloud platforms like Azure, AWS or Google can help you a long way to implement reliable queues.

> we need
>   to sort by notification_time, not insert time, and we need to allow
>   deletes.

here because you have "multiple nodes" that "create notifications", you can use a simple pipes and filters architecture, whereby you pump message into an unsorted queue first and then an other processor can pick up those message and insert them into the sorted queue. This will add another layer or Reliability/failure which ever way you look at it. however will mean that sour sorting processor is independent and can scale independently as well.
you can also you the sorter to pump the messages into a datastore instead of a queue if you want. Again all of this will depend on the reliability requirements and how much time, effort and money you want to throw at it.

Comment: Yeah that's the conclusion I came to over the weekend. My proposed architecture would be a Kafka (because we can reconsume) topic consumed by an application using java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue and then re-publishing them at the appropriate time. There's still some ways to get caught out though, although they can be solved (needing to check if the notification has been sent or not at startup) but they can be solved.